# sieve of eratostheness algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sieve

I have this function for calculate prime numbers with sieve of eratosthenes. I have one error i don't understand why.

```
def era1(n):

    llista1 = []
    llista2 = []
    i = 2

    while(i<(n+1)):
        llista1.append(i)
        i = i + 1

    while (llista1[0]<(n**0.5)):
        llista2.append(llista1[0])    
        for j in range ((len(llista1))-1):
            if (llista1[j] % llista1[0] == 0) :  #<------- error list index out of range
                llista1.remove(llista1[j])
        llista1.remove(llista1[0])
    print llista2
```

Comment: I recommend renaming your variables so the code is clearer. In particular, the two lists could be called, for example, "unsievedNumbersList" and "sievedNumbersList". Something that describes what they are better.

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of removing items in a list while iterating through them. You've specified your for loop to run for `n` amount of times, but by the time you get to the nth item, the item which was once there has been moved back a few indexes because you're removing items from the list.

You'll need to re-think your method in reimplementing the Sieve. I can't 100% follow your approach to it, but I'm sure it might involve having a secondary list. Whitelist, don't blacklist :).

Also, [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a cool function to look into.

Comment: Interesting- would removing things every iteration also cause efficiency problems in that case, since the indices have to be recalculated all the time?

Comment: @ColmBhandal If you were to recalculate the indexes, then yes of course. However, this should really be avoided since there would always be a better way to fix it. Python makes no attempt to recalculate indexes (hence the IndexError)

Comment: @Terry , how does `enumerate` help here? Does it create a shallow copy?

Comment: @TerryA I guess what I was asking was this. When you index a list in Python, how does Python know what element to retrieve if you've removed stuff before that element? E.g. I have letters = {A, B, C, D, E}. If I do letters[3] I get D. Then I do letters.remove(C). And now when I index letters[3] I get E. How does Python know that letters[3] is now E, vs. D, without having to do some computation to shift the indices down?

Comment: @KaushikNP Oh, I just brought up `enumerate()` for the sake of not having to do `range(len(...`

Comment: @ColmBhandal You ask a very good question, and I've been trying to research it for the past 10-15 minutes and I can't come up with an adequate answer. The [source code for list.remove](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2289) seems to suggest that it slices the list from both directions of the object removed (eg: `L=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; L.remove(3) == L[0:2]+L[3:]`) - although I could be wrong here. There is no 'map' for indexing (i.e, Python doesn't know that `letters[2]` was ever `C`, it just finds the 3rd element in the array and returns it).

Comment: @ColmBhandal So when one element is removed, "recalculating the indexes" doesn't really exist. Indexing is always the same. The only performance differences would be that `list.remove` is `O(n)`, and calling it multiple times would be slower than generating a new list.

Comment: @TerryA yeah it also seems to imply that retrieval of an item is `O(n)` too, which seems mighty wasteful for something to use inside a for loop. Anyway, if we take a number of steps back, I think your comment says it all: whitelist, don't blacklist! ;)

Answer (score 0):

might be useful for anyone that still looking for this algorithm approach

```
def SieveOfEratosthenes(n): 
    # Create a boolean array "prime[0..n]" and initialize 
    # all entries it as true. A value in prime[i] will 
    # finally be false if i is Not a prime, else true. 
    prime = [True for i in range(n + 1)] 
    p = 2
    while (p * p <= n): 
            
        # If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a prime 
        if (prime[p] == True): 
                
            # Update all multiples of p 
            for i in range(p * 2, n + 1, p): 
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1
    prime[0]= False
    prime[1]= False
    # Print all prime numbers 
    for p in range(n + 1): 
        if prime[p]: 
            print (p) 
    
# driver program 
if __name__=='__main__': 
    n = 30
    print ("Following are the prime numbers smaller") 
    print ("than or equal to", n )
    SieveOfEratosthenes(n)
```